# How to change endpoint address for generate JWT token

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, authorization, jwt

By default spring boot web security use `/login` endpoint to login and generate token. However I need `/user/login` endpoint to do that. My WebSecurityConfig looks like that:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            // this disables session creation on Spring Security
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

I wanted to know how to change endpoint address for generating JWT token? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can change .loginPage() params like this;

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/about").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/user/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but this not solve the problem, because formLogin() generate login page and I would like to avoid that. I just want to change default endpoint '/login' to '/user/login'

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Check this out : [link](http://www.svlada.com/jwt-token-authentication-with-spring-boot/)

Answer (score 0):

I did a little investigation and it's impossible to do that, because to generate token I use my own filter (JWTAuthenticationFilter). That filter extends from UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and there is a hardcoded endpoint in constructor:

```
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {
  super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"));
}
```